# Elasticsearch filter only inner data

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to ES, I have an index has a nested type

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "product": {
            "properties": {
                "productid": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "description": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "inventory": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "location": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "productvalue": {
                            "type": "double"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have inserted following 2 products in this:

```
POST productlist/product/1
{
    "productid": 1,
            "description": "rose red",
    "inventory": [
        {
            "location": 1,
            "productvalue": 100
        },
        {
            "branch": 2,
            "onhand": 50
        }
    ]
}

POST productlist/product/2
{
    "productid": 2,
            "description": "rose purple",
    "inventory": [
        {
            "branch": 1,
            "onhand": 1000
        },
        {
            "branch": 3,
            "onhand": 500
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a sample query as below:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "fields": [
                            "description"
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match": "75%",
                        "operator": "and",
                        "query": "rose",
                        "type": "phrase_prefix"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "inventory",
                        "query": {
                            "term": {
                                "inventory.branch": "1"
                            }
                        },
                        "inner_hits": {}
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This query returns me both my records with the nested inventory object having 2 records each. I want to get both the main product records but in each inventory record I want to get only the value for location 1 and no other location.
How can this be achieved?
Thanks

Comment: Can you check your index again? Does it not have fields like branch?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your query with sample data in question.  Below is the result I got

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index113",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "JuZ_DXoBa-D2ll-06dGB",
        "_score" : 1.1335313,
        "_source" : {
          "productid" : 2,
          "description" : "rose purple",
          "inventory" : [
            {
              "branch" : 1,
              "onhand" : 1000
            },
            {
              "branch" : 3,
              "onhand" : 500
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {          -------> nested matched document
          "inventory" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "index113",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "JuZ_DXoBa-D2ll-06dGB",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "inventory",
                    "offset" : 0
                  },
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "branch" : 1,
                    "onhand" : 1000
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index113",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "J-Z_DXoBa-D2ll-08tH8",
        "_score" : 1.1335313,
        "_source" : {
          "productid" : 2,
          "description" : "rose purple",
          "inventory" : [
            {
              "branch" : 1,
              "onhand" : 1000
            },
            {
              "branch" : 3,
              "onhand" : 500
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "inventory" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "index113",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "J-Z_DXoBa-D2ll-08tH8",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "inventory",
                    "offset" : 0
                  },
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "branch" : 1,
                    "onhand" : 1000
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Though nested sub-documents are treated as separate documents, _source will still retrieve everything under a given path.

So you will only get matched sub documents under  inner hits (highlighted in result).

If you don't want all nested documents, you can explicitly provide _source in query and exclude "inventory field"

ex

```
"query":{....},
"_source": ["productid","description"]
```

Result:

```
{
        "_index" : "index113",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "J-Z_DXoBa-D2ll-08tH8",
        "_score" : 1.1335313,
        "_source" : {
          "productid" : 2,
          "description" : "rose purple"
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "inventory" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "index113",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "J-Z_DXoBa-D2ll-08tH8",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "inventory",
                    "offset" : 0
                  },
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "branch" : 1,
                    "onhand" : 1000
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. The inventory data for each product will be a massive list and thats why I want to filter only required records from the inventory data. But I also dont want the inner filter to affect the outer result set, do you think that is possible?

Comment: @Come2Searcher you can remove inventory from _source by providing the fields you need to be returned and use inner hits to return matched inventory. I don't  understand what you mean by "dont want the inner filter to affect the outer result set"